# Bootstrap 5 Jumbotron with video background doesn't play video

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I created a simple jumbotron component and set the background to play a video. For some reason, it is not playing the video at all. I **can load the video in a URL** just fine and the video plays fine so I am not sure what is causing the issue.

here is the simple HTML:

```html
<div class="jumbotron homehero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        Left column content goes here
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        Right column content goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS

```css
.jumbotron.homehero {
  background-image: url('https://phasefivemedia.com/external/video_bg_1080.mp4');
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!

I have a pen here:
https://codepen.io/SimplyMarkB/pen/WNgweoV

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score -1):

```html
 <div class="jumbotron homehero">
<video autoplay muted loop id="yourVideo">
  <source src="https://phasefivemedia.com/external/video_bg_1080.mp4;" type="video/mp4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        Left column content goes here
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        Right column content goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would work but I lose my col content

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).